# OpenCV: dx and dy conversion from world to pixel coordinates

Tags: opencv, pixel, derivative

This is probably more of a mathematical question, I have the values of dx and dy calculated for an OpenCV application, both values are in world coordinates. Now if I convert them to pixel coordinates, will their signs change ? For instance, if my world coordinate dx > 0, and then I convert to pixel coordinate, will it remain > 0 ?

Also, I'm quite new to openCV, what's the easiest function in OpenCV to convert from world coordinates to pixel coordinates ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why there would be a sign shift here, unless some kind of overflow error. If you are uncertain, simply have an assertion (if you think the error will happen somewhat frequently and you can test it) or negate it (if you can't test it) if it is >0.